# How to make 'www' optional in a Hostname Route in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, router, hostname, http-host

Let's say I have the domain "example.com"
I would like to add a route such as when the URL is "example.com/whatever/follows" it redirects to "http://www.example.com/whatever/follows" (forwarding the query strings too).

Basically I would like to translate into Zend the following Apache Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

How can we do that if possible at all?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to keep it as a apache rule, as it is faster and is the correct way to do. WWW is actually a subdomain value not an optional feature and it should not be present, unless you want the subdomain.

Also check the [no-www](http://no-www.org/) site.